# Angular's Child Routes can't work

Tags: angular

Hy can someone help me, i got stuck in angular 6 child routes. My angular child routes cant work in lazy load.

this is my app-routing modules

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'master',
    loadChildren: './modules/master/master.module#MasterModule'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    // preload all modules; optionally we could
    // implement a custom preloading strategy for just some
    // of the modules (PRs welcome )
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  })],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

then, this is my master-routing modules

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DokterComponent } from './dokter/dokter.component';
import { MasterComponent } from './master.component';

const routes: Routes = [  
  {
    path: '',
    component: MasterComponent
    children: [
      { path: "", component: DokterComponent, pathMatch: "full" },
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MasterRoutingModule { }
```

when i tried to access /master/dokter, there is no error message, but the dokterComponent cant be loaded. thanks for your attention.

Comment: please add pathMatch: 'full' like this :  {
    path: '',
    component: MasterComponent, pathMatch: 'full'
  },

Comment: Do you have an error in your command line console ?

Comment: @FatehMohamed it isn't required when there's no `redirectTo` property

Comment: @trichetriche there is no error in my console.

Comment: And when you inspect your router outlet, what are you having ?

Comment: @FatehMohamed Thanks, it works for me.

Comment: @trichetriche, before i added "pathMatch: 'full'". My DokterComponent cant be loaded. it always shows master Component.

Comment: @trichetriche , thanks for your help :)